# How to get Magento Review, just average reviews no HTML

Tags: magento

I have been using

```
if ($product->getRatingSummary()):
    echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product);
endif;
```

But that returns some HTML for Reviews.
Problem is with the variable **$this** which is not accessible inside a function. Is there any way to get the reviews value (Not the whole HTML) without using $this variable and just giving the product id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `getSummaryHtml` Method of `Mage_Review_Block_Helper`, you will get idea how magento calculate review summary.

You can use the below code with current product object `$_product` to set rating summary in product object.

```
Mage::getModel('review/review')->getEntitySummary($_product, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

After that you can fetch summary using the below method:

```
echo $_product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
echo $_product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
```